# InlineKeyboardMarkup telegram

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Помогите составить `InlineKeyboardMarkup`

Хочу что бы в `InlineKeyboardMarkup` были кнопки `InlineKeyboardCallbackButton` и `InlineKeyboardUrlButton`, как это сделано [тут](https://core.telegram.org/bots/2-0-intro#switch-to-inline-buttons)

Делаю так, но выдает синтаксическую ошибку.

```
var keyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(new[]{
new[]
{
    new InlineKeyboardUrlButton("site", "https://google.com"),
},
new[]
{
    new InlineKeyboardCallbackButton("menu", "menu",
}});
```

Comment: Какую ошибку выдаёт? Так или иначе, стоит указать тип элементов первого массива, так как первый вложенный возвращает `InlineKeyboardUrlButton`, второй вложенный `InlineKeyboardCallbackButton`, и компилятор не может на основе этих данных вывести базовый тип, удовлетворяющий обоим элементам. При этом сигнатура вызываемого метода не является основанием для вывода того или иного типа в данном случае. Короче, всё зло от анонимных массивов. ;)

Comment: какую библиотеку для работы с апи используете?

Comment: @Anatol https://www.nuget.org/packages/Telegram.Bot/13.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var keyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup
   {
      InlineKeyboard = new[]
         {
             new[] { InlineKeyboardButton.WithUrl("site", "https://google.com") },
             new[] { InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("menu", "menu") }
         }
   };
```